# Custom Rendering on IOS a CardView from Frame

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to make a CardView on IOS Xamarin Forms by subclassing the Frame and making a custom renderer. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Upon looking into the API on setting a shadow, I've done this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CardView), typeof(CardViewRenderer))]
namespace TrabbleMobile.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CardViewRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            var cardView = (CardView)this.Element;

            using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
            {
                //nfloat cornerRadius = 2;
                float shadowOffsetWidth = 2;
                float shadowOffsetHeight = 4;
                var shadowColor = new CGColor(0, 0, 0, (nfloat)0.5);
                var boxColor = new CGColor(255, 255, 255);
                var shadowBlur = (float)0.5;
                var offset = new CGSize(shadowOffsetWidth, shadowOffsetHeight);

                context.SetShadow(offset, shadowBlur, shadowColor);
```

However, it does not render as it should and no shadow at all.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/FrameRenderer.cs#L26

Comment: Hi, can you formalize this in to an answer? I used the link to the documentation you commented to solve this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this, and the way that I did this is thru custom rendering on IOS and here is the custom renderer code:

```
    public class CardViewRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            SetupShadowLayer();
            base.Draw(rect);
        }

        void SetupShadowLayer()
        {
            Layer.CornerRadius = 2; // 5 Default
            if (Element.BackgroundColor == Xamarin.Forms.Color.Default)
            {
                Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
            }
            else
            {
                Layer.BackgroundColor = Element.BackgroundColor.ToCGColor();
            }

            Layer.ShadowRadius = 2; // 5 Default
            Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.4f; // 0.8f Default
            Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(0f, 2.5f);

            if (Element.OutlineColor == Xamarin.Forms.Color.Default)
            {
                Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
            }
            else
            {
                Layer.BorderColor = Element.OutlineColor.ToCGColor();
                Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            }

            Layer.RasterizationScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
            Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but if you click and scroll to the CardView Renderer listview, tha CardView Renderer returns to its original state.